# Calling unset variable doesn't throw notice after calling it as a reference

Tags: php

There are 3 var_dumps in this code (the second is commented out).
If I run it, the first and the third var_dumps produce a notice (both), as expected.
After uncommenting the second var_dump, the third var_dump stops throwing a notice.
My question is: why?
I would still expect a notice there, because in the 3rd var_dump I still read a variable which isn't set before (as the isset indicates).

```
<?php

function nvl(&$var, $default = 'hello')
{
    return !isset($var) ? $default : $var;
}

var_dump($a, isset($a));
//var_dump(nvl($a), isset($a));
var_dump($a, isset($a));
```

Comment: because when this line  `var_dump(nvl($a), isset($a));` is un-commented then $a is created

Comment: Because by calling the function and passing the variable by reference you create it: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php

Comment: No, $a isn't created. Whenever I ask after nvl($a) if $a is set, the answer is no. Which is good, because that's not the point of that function.

Comment: Oh you are right. My problem was that isset returns false if it's set to null. Hmp. My bad. Sorry. For me it wasn't really logical that if I SET it to null then it isn't set.

Comment: @AstigNaGahum $a is created and assigned NULL the link refered by Rizier123 perfectly explain the answer

Answer (score 0):

becouse to be able to pass it to `nvl` as reference `$a` is created.

if you remove `&` from nvl first arg you will get 3 notices.

Comment: Yes it seems logicaI, but still it's not perfectly clear to me.

isset checks for being set. It's not set, so isset returns false, which is okay.

notice is thrown for being not defined. Before referencing it, it isn't -> notice is thrown. Okay.

After referencing it, notice disappears, so reference $a is created, which means it's defined now?

So having a reference created means it's being defined as well?

Comment: @AstigNaGahum  a perfetc link given by Rizer in comment, go for it and you will get clear picture

Comment: thats becouse you don't have to declare variables in php, consider `
var_dump($a, isset($a));$a=1;` $a is magicaly created for you same case